Enumeration and The Tao Te Ching
I would like to know if the oldest copy of the Tao Te Ching and the poems had been enumerated/titled. All the translations have them numbered 1-81. I would like to know if this is accurate.

This book has 81 chapters. Originally, it had no chapters. Thereafter it had 68 chapters, now it has 81. The word "chapter"  comes from  a diminutive of Latin caput, basically meaning heading.


道德经分上下两篇，原文上篇《德经》、下篇《道经》，不分章，后改为《道经》37章在前，第38章之后为《德经》，并分为81章。

-- 百度百科
Just as @Pedroski says in the comments, it was originally not divided into chapters, but was later divided into 81 chapters.
